# svg image with 100% width isn't constantly 100% wide

Tags: css, image, svg, responsive-design, width

I'd like to get an (svg-)image responsively filling up 100% width (at height:auto).
when i decrease the size of my browser window gradually, the image size appears to "lag" — jumping a little smaller at a some points, then back to 100%, and so on.

the code is:

```
<body>
<img class="zigzag" width="100%" height="auto" src="images/wavegreynoborderstraight.svg">
</body
```

no margin / padding set on the body and nothing alike.
is this a common problem?
I'm testing in chrome (31.0).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you didn't closed the body-tag correctly. Maybe, if you made this mistake in your document too, that could be the bad guy.
Else, we need to know the embeded svg-code - it could be invalid...

I tried your code in firefox(26.0) and chrome(31.0) with my own svg files and it works well in both, even with unclosed body...

It also may be, that you svg is too complex. (too many decimal places or anchors)
Try to simplify the paths in your SVG editor and export it with 3 decimal places.

Let me know if it had helped.